# Line control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

I am new to .net world, got some work to convert the VB 6 code to VB.net 
where OptionLine is a LINE Control & intCurrentControlTop is a integer variable

```
     'Create line
        Load Line(count)
        Line(count).Y1 = 20
        Line(count).Y2 = 30
        Line(count).X1 = Line(0).X1
        Line(count).X2 = Line(0).X2
        Line(count).Visible = True
```

when  I am trying to convert the above code using VS2005 wizard, it treated Line variable as Label and give me below version

```
    Line As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.LabelArray  
                Line.Load(count)
                Line(count).Y1 = 20
                Line(count).Y2 = 30
                Line(count).X1 = Line(0).X1
                Line(count).X2 = Line(0).X2
                Line(count).Visible = True
```

Now when I am compiling , Error = X1 is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.Label

can some one help

Comment: You need to use the VB Powerpacks component to be able to use the Line control in .NET, but you still can't use control arrays like that. Some research is required to see differences between VB6 and .Net: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kehz1dz1(v=vs.90).aspx